# How can i import this function?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

Im trying to build a POS system that communicates with the kitchen. Right now im trying to import the reducer to my express server but i cant seem to be able to import it as a function nor as a module. I am using React and useContext with useReducer and want to be able to have a central nervsystem to manage all the dispatch actions. Here is the affecting minimized pages if it helps:

```
INDEX.JS
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const chooseSystem = require('./../kassa/controller/login/login.tsx');
import {reducer} from './src/utils/reducer'


const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://192.168.0.25:8100",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
  });

io.on('connection', (socket) => 
{ 
    // Landing page, user chooses system to log in to POS or kitchen
    socket.on('CHOOSESYSTEM', dispatchFunction => {
        chooseSystem.chooseSystem(dispatchFunction);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Listening on 3000");});


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


REDUCER.TSX
import React from "react";
import { GlobalInitContextProps, GlobalStateProps } from "./interfaces";

  const reducer = (state = initGlobalState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOG_IN_TO_POS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: {
          inSystem: true,
          inPOS: true,
        },
      };
    case "LOG_IN_TO_KITCHEN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: {
          inSystem: true,
          inPOS: false,
        },
      };
    case "GO_TO":
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return new Error("Something went wrong with the reducer");
  }
};

// Export
export {reducer};
```

I have tried exporting it as a module like this: module.exports.reducer = reducer and use require('') in my index.js but it does not work. Module is not found. Dont mind the functionality as it does not make sense without the rest of the pages

This is my project structure:

- KASSA

  - INDEX.JS
  - SRC

    - UTILS

      - REDUCER

Comment: Why do you want to use a React reducer in the backend?

Comment: I dont know. Is there a better way to handle the global state or to manipulate it ?

Answer (score 0):

try exporting default the reducer

```
    REDUCER.TSX
import React from "react";
import { GlobalInitContextProps, GlobalStateProps } from "./interfaces";

  export default (state = initGlobalState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOG_IN_TO_POS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: {
          inSystem: true,
          inPOS: true,
        },
      };
    case "LOG_IN_TO_KITCHEN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: {
          inSystem: true,
          inPOS: false,
        },
      };
    case "GO_TO":
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return new Error("Something went wrong with the reducer");
  }
};
```

And the importing it like

```
import reducer from './src/utils/reducer'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your method but unfortunately i get error still saying: SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier. "import reducer from './src/utils/reducer'. the unexpected identifier points to the word reducer right after "import"